# Offending Command error while Printing EPS

Tags: printing, command, postscript, eps

I am printing an EPS File generated with following credentials.

```
%-12345X@PJL JOB
@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = POSTSCRIPT 
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%Title: InvoiceDetail_combine
%%Creator: PScript5.dll Version 5.2.2
%%CreationDate: 10/7/2011 4:46:59
%%For: Administrator
%%BoundingBox: (atend)
%%Pages: (atend)
%%Orientation: Portrait
%%PageOrder: Special
%%DocumentNeededResources: (atend)
%%DocumentSuppliedResources: (atend)
%%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
%%TargetDevice: (HP Color LaserJet 4500) (2014.200) 0
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%EndComments
```

While doing Selection Printing on Ricoh Afficio 2090 or any other drivers/printers get the following error printed on the sheets

```
ERROR: undefined
OFFENDING COMMAND: F4S47
Stack:

.
```

Kindly Review and suggest a turn around for the same as i am already stuck in this hell. I have tried to convert/extract in PS but all in vain. I am using gsview to Print and view these files.

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem:

> %%PageOrder: Special

A ps document with "Special" page order can *NOT* be re-ordered. You cannot do a selection or range with this file because it is broken for this use. You must reprocess the file using Distiller or ghostscript (ps2ps or ps2pdf) in order to print selected or re-ordered pages from the document.

You can avoid this by generating your postscript files with a *real* Postscript™ driver (one not created by Microsoft).

The [GSView Documentation](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/gsviewen.htm#Common_Problems) has more about this.

**Previously:**

This line ...

> %%TargetDevice: (HP Color LaserJet 4500) (2014.200) 0

... tells us that the file was generated with HP printers as a target.  So this *really* is not an EPS file. Because it's not Encapsulatable. To generate output on a printer the file has to execute the `showpage` operator, which is a *no-no* for EPS files.

So uncheck the EPS box (it's a big fat lie, anyway), and select (install) a Generic Postscript driver. If you need to send it to multiple makes of printer, the file needs to make as few assumptions about the printer as possible.

Comment: luser can you elaborate some generic Postscript Drivers. SO that i can try on it.

Comment: @Azwar I'll try. But the best place for this kind of info is Don Lancaster's site. It used to be the case that the easiest way to get a decent postscript file on Windows is to install a FILE: printer with the Apple Laserwriter driver. Using FILE: as the printer means that every time you print to this "printer", a dialog opens asking you where to save the file. I expect the best driver now is from Adobe. But whatever you do, remember PS is for printing, EPS is for embedding in a larger document.

Comment: @AzwarDurrani you might want to take this to [comp.lang.postscript](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.postscript/topics?start=) for more postscript experts in a threaded forum. (Ken and I are both there, too.)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is that this is not a valid EPS file, as it has PJL attached at the front. Many PostScript printers will strip this off, but by no means all.

This probably is not the source of the problem.

There is no way to 'review' the problem as you have not supplied the complete PostScript program. Without that there is no way to tell what is actually wrong, the error message tells you that the interpreter encountered 'F4547' while trying to parse a token, and that this has not been defined as a routine.

Most likely the file is corrupt, either damaged in some way, or possibly it is a biinary file and has been transmitted by some process which does has done some kind of conversion (CR/LF is common). The offending command looks like its ASCIIHex encoded, so that may be a red herring.

If you want additional help, you are going to have to make the whole program available somewhere.

Comment: Ken kindly let me know from where you can review this. so that i can put it up. As i am working on it to resolve the issue and have to complete the printing task. your help is highly appriciated.

Comment: Anywhere public, or that you are prepared to grant me access to.